# how to void callback hell in typescript

Tags: typescript, callback

I know callback hell is bad, but I can't solve this problem in typescript.
if I want to remove a category:

first check the category exists
second check the category has parent?

if has update category's parent children collection

finally callback to controller send message to client.

anybody could help me out?
here is my method code:

```
removeCategory(catId: string, callback: (error: any, result: any) => void) {
    var msg = {
        "message": "",
        "statescode": 200,
        "error": null
    };
    console.log("find category");
    if (catId) {
        super.findById(catId, (getError: any, getEntity: any) => {
            if (getError) {
                msg.message = "can't find this item: " + catId;
                msg.statescode = 404;
                msg.error = getError;
                callback(msg, null);
            } else {
                console.log("find category");
                super.remove(catId, (delError: any, delEntity: any) => {
                    if (delError) {
                        msg.message = "something wrong with remove this category: " + getEntity.name;
                        msg.statescode = 400;
                        msg.error = delError;
                        callback(msg, null);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (getEntity.parent) {
                            var parentId = getEntity.parent;

                            super.update(parentId, { $pull: { childrens: getEntity._id } }, (putError: any, putEntity: any) => {
                                if (putError) {
                                    msg.message = "can't update this item:" + item.name;
                                    msg.statescode = 500;
                                    msg.error = putError;
                                    callback(msg, null);
                                }
                                else {
                                    callback(null, getEntity);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            callback(null, getEntity);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        msg.message = "entityId can't be empty!";
        msg.statescode = 400;
        callback(msg, null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a proposal in Typescript 2.0 regarding [Async Functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1664) which may help you, you may keep eye on that.

You may also look into [Async.js library](https://github.com/caolan/async) for now, it also helps in this scenario.

Comment: thanks for your help, I think this will help me : http://www.summa.com/blog/avoiding-callback-hell-while-using-mongoose

Answer (score 1):

using promise in mongoose could fix this problem.
here is code:

```
createCategory(catEntity: ICategoryModel, callback: (error: any, result: any) => void) {
    var parentCat: ICategoryModel;
    var postEntity: ICategoryModel;
    if (catEntity && catEntity.parent) {
        this._categoryRep.findById(catEntity.parent).then((getCat: ICategoryModel) => {
            if (!getCat) {
                throw new Error("can not find this category's parent");
            }
            return getCat;
        }).then((getCat: ICategoryModel) => {
            parentCat = getCat;
            return this._categoryRep.create(catEntity);
        }).then((postCat: ICategoryModel) => {
            postEntity = postCat;
            return this._categoryRep.update(parentCat._id, { $push: { childrens: postEntity._id } });
        }).then((putInfo: any) => {
            callback(null, postEntity);
        }).then(null, (error: any) => {
            callback(error, null);
        });
    } else {
        this._categoryRep.create(catEntity).then((postCat: ICategoryModel) => {
            callback(null, postEntity);
        }).then(null, (error: any) => {
            callback(error, null);
        });
    }
}
```